# Handle touch on scren vertically in android

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I am playing video from web in `VideoView` in landscape mode. Now I want to control its volume when I move finger on screen vertically. When I scroll down to up volume should increase and when scroll finger up to down then volume should decrease. How can I get this type of control?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the EventListner interface will solve the problem since in this you can handle all the touch events.So handle the touch event along y axis then you can control your volume.